# VBscript - select file based on priority

Tags: vbscript

I have a folder that I will be looping through to process files differently based on their filenames.  Doing good on my script (first one!), until I realized there will be filenames that have also have numbers representing priority.  For example in the folder there may be:

```
'NV_CX67_mainx.dxf'
'NV_CX67_mainx1.dxf'
'NV_CX67_mainx2.dxf '
'NV_CX67_mainxroad.dxf'
'NV_CX67_motx.dxf'
'NV_CX67_resxroad.dxf'
```

The mainx, mainx1 and mainx2 are the same file type but mainx2 has priority and should be the only one processed.   Currently, my statement is:

```
If Instr(1,FileRef, "mainx",1) then
```

How might I add a 2nd filter to process only the file with the highest number before moving onto the next file?

Answer (score 1):

You are going to have run through the following process

1. Sort your input files
2. Loop through each file one by one
3. Compare the current file to the previous one you looked at minus the numbers to see if it greater.
4. Only process an item you have scanned all the similar items to ensure this one has the largest number

I wrote up an example below. Notice only NV_CX67_mainx4.dxf,  and NV_CX67_mainxroad.dxf get processed:

```
Option Explicit

Dim i, sBaseFileName, sPrevFileName, prevBaseFile
sPrevFileName = "~"
prevBaseFile = "~"
Dim arr(5)
'Initialize test array. This will need to be sorted for this code to work properly
arr(0) = "NV_CX67_mainx.dxf"
arr(1) = "NV_CX67_mainx4.dxf"
arr(2) = "NV_CX67_mainx2.dxf"
arr(3) = "NV_CX67_mainxroad.dxf"
arr(4) = "NV_CX67_motx.dxf"  
arr(5) = "NV_CX67_resxroad.dxf" 

'Loop through the array
For i = LBound(arr) to UBound(arr) 
    If Instr(1, arr(i), "mainx",1) Then 'Check prev qualifier
        sBaseFileName = getsBaseFileName(arr(i))

        'First Case     
        If prevBaseFile = "~" Then
            prevBaseFile = sBaseFileName
            sPrevFileName = arr(i)
        'Tie - Figure out which one to keep based on number at end of file name
        ElseIf prevBaseFile = sBaseFileName Then
            sPrevFileName = GetMaxFile(sPrevFileName, arr(i))
            prevBaseFile = getsBaseFileName(sPrevFileName)

        'New Case - Process prev case
        Else
            'Process File
            MsgBox ("Processing " + sPrevFileName)
            'Capture new current file for future processing
            sPrevFileName = arr(i)
            prevBaseFile = getsBaseFileName(sPrevFileName)          
        End If
    End If
Next
'If last file was valid process it
If sPrevFileName <> "~" Then
    MsgBox ("Processing " + sPrevFileName)
End If

'Return the larger of the two files based on numbers at end. 
'Note "file9.txt" > "file10.txt" in this code
Function GetMaxFile(sFile1, sFile2)
    GetMaxFile = sFile1
    If sFile2 > sFile1 Then
        GetMaxFile = sFile2
    End If
End Function

'Return the file without extension and trailing numbers
'getsBaseFileName("hello123.txt") returns "hello"
Function getsBaseFileName(sFile)
    Dim sFileRev
    Dim iPos

    getsBaseFileName = sFile
    sFileRev = StrReverse(sFile)

    'Get rid of the extension
    iPos = Instr(1, sFileRev, ".",1)
    If iPos < 1 Then
        Exit Function
    End If
    sFileRev = Right(sFileRev, Len(sFileRev)-iPos)

    'Get rid of trailing numbers
    Do
        If InStr(1, "1234567890", Left(sFileRev, 1), 1) Then
            sFileRev = Right(sFileRev, Len(sFileRev)-1)
        Else
            Exit Do
        End If
     Loop While(Len(sFileRev) > 0)

    getsBaseFileName =  StrReverse(sFileRev)
End Function
```